# "A scored 66%, 10% more than B?" What is B's score?

Tags: word-usage

It sounds like a maths question but what I care about is the usage of the term 'percentage'. Can anyone tell me, how to go about the correct way to use when the meaning of the sentence is:

- B scored 60%
- B scored 56%.

Comment: I suggest that you modify the title, it looks and reads like a riddle. It will invite users to close it as off-topic.

Comment: I also downvoted because it is unclear, you ask about the word percentage but you don't write how you think the sentence is read. The title is a question while the examples listed are only percentages.

Comment: I see what you're trying to get at but I'd still class this as a maths question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math question.  You can have the same question in other languages.

Comment: @GEdgar I think OP is looking for the words "percentage point".

Comment: I also voted to close. This feels like a discussion of how math uses the concept of percentage rather than how English users use the word percentage. The word "percentage" is never used in examples, so we're in some weird symbol area. It could perhaps be salvaged if rukuto will clarify what he means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "A scored 66%, 10% more than B?” What is B's score? [60%]
>
> "A scored 66%, 10 **percentage points** more than B?” What is B's score? [56%]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point

Obviously, the first sentence will still be somewhat ambiguous, but at least the second one should be perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

> A scored 66%, 10% more than B

In the given example, it's unclear whether the "10%" in the second clause is a percentage of A's score or a percentage of the overall score.

The easiest way to clarify this is to give both scores in terms of an overall percentage. This avoids any confusion over what the percentages apply to and also avoids testing their math skills.

> A scored 66%, B scored 56%
>   or
>   A scored 66%, B scored 60%